# What is the difference between 'many other of ~ ' and 'many other ~'?

Tags: meaning

I have rarely encountered ***many other of***. What is the difference between ***many other of ~*** and ***many other ~***?

> ***Many other of*** his films were centred on such well-known characters as Sherlock Holmes, Oliver Twist, Salome, Richelieu, Moses,
> and Saul and David. - Encyclopedia Britannica

Comment: Which Britannica article is this from, please?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Looks like it's from the entry on [J. Stuart Blackton](https://www.britannica.com/biography/J-Stuart-Blackton).

Answer (score 1):

> Many other of his films ...

is at best an awkward construction, and I incline to think it actually ungrammatical.

The usual way to express this thought is

> Many of his other films were centered on ...

Here "other" modifies "films", presumably films other than one mentioned previously.

Also possible would be a construction such as

> Many other films of his were centered on ...

or

> Many others of his films were centered on ...

but I don't like this last version.

Comment: I appreciate your help, David. Thank you.